# Comparing rows within groups in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have an example dataFrame

```
dF <- structure(list(status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
      1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("complete", "go", "no go", "revise"
      ), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
      2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("101", "102", "103"), class =              
      "factor"), 
          date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
          3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")),           
          .Names = c("status", 
          "group", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to compare the `dF$status[2]` to `dF$status[1]` and `dF$status[3]` to `dF$status[2]` and so on, within each group.  I can do this relatively easily with a simple function and `ddply()`:

```
  state_change_function <- function(x){

    tmp <- integer(length = nrow(x))

    for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
      if(x$statu[i] == x$status[i-1]){ 
        tmp[i] <- "no change"
      } else {
        tmp[i] <- "state change"
      }
    }
    return(tmp)
  }

  state_change <- ddply(dF, .(group), state_change_function)
```

This gives a very simple output that I can then `melt()` with the `reshape` package and attach to my `dF` as a new column.

```
> state_change
  group V1           V2           V3           V4
1   101  0    no change    no change state change
2   102  0 state change state change    no change
3   103  0 state change    no change state change
```

My problem is when I have a different number of rows among groups.  For example, if the `dF` suddenly lost one row of where `dF$group == 102",

```
dF1 <- structure(list(status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("complete", "go", "no go", "revise"
), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("101", "102", "103"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), .Names =    
    c("status", 
    "group", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

then running the same function causes an error:

```
state_change <- ddply(dF1, .(group), state_change_function)
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id,     id_as_factor) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths
```

I found a partial solution on SO that uses a different function:

```
state_change_function <- function(data){    
  output <- integer(length(rrsIdeas)-1)
    for(i in seq_along(output)){
    output[[i]] <- (data$status[i] == data$status[i+1])
    }
  return(output)
}

state_change <- ddply(dF1, .(group), state_change_function)
```

and provides a different output:

```
> state_change
  group V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17
1   101  1  1  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   102  0  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   103  0  1  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

My problem with this output is that it's much more difficult to `melt()` and append to my original `dF1` without a great deal more work because group `102` has data in a few number of columns that `101` or `102`.  This is especially difficult because I have over 1500 groups to which I'm applying this function whose `nrow()` may change through time.

What I'd like to have is a function that compares each row to the previous row within a group and--ideally--outputs a dataFrame like

```
group  V1
101    0
101    no change
101    no change
101    state change
102    0
102    state change
102    state change
102    no change
etc...
```

but, if some groups have fewer rows than others, can limit the number of rows in the dataFrame for that group.

I've searched here and elsewhere for help but have not found what I'm looking for.  I'm sure this is possible and I may be overlooking something very simple.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dF1)[,V1:=c("0",ifelse(head(status,-1)!=status[-1],'change','no change')),group]

#      status group date        V1
# 1: complete   101    1         0
# 2: complete   101    2 no change
# 3: complete   101    3 no change
# 4:   revise   101    4    change
# 5:    no go   102    2         0
# 6: complete   102    3    change
# 7: complete   102    4 no change
# 8:       go   103    1         0
# 9:   revise   103    2    change
#10:   revise   103    3 no change
#11:       go   103    4    change
```

Comment: This was exceptionally difficult for me to figure out how to use.  I thought it would be as simple as "plug and play" with my actual data (i.e., as easy as it was with the example data), but that was not the case.  Through significant headaches, I learned that if you try to use `group_by(group)` from `dplyr` before you use the `data.table` function you posted above, it's not going to work.

Comment: It's better not to mix `dplyr` and `data.table` to parse/reformat/aggregate data :)

Comment: As a new `data.table` user, I learned that lesson the hard way.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dF$status <- as.character(dF$status)

dF %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(change = ifelse(status == lag(status), "no change", "change"))
```

Comment: I'm wondering why this solution won't work without the factor to string conversion.

Comment: Most likely because the factor numeric values don't match up with the alpha levels.